# How to track item's absolute position

Tags: qml, qtquick2

The task is to track item's absolute position.

Since item's coordinates are specified relative to its direct parent there's no way to know when item's absolute position have changed in case its parent moves.

Considering example below, I'd like to know when `rect2` visually moves due to its parent, i.e. `rect1`, motion triggered by spacebar key stroke:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 200
    focus: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        x: 200
        width: 400
        height: 200
        color: "salmon"

        Rectangle {
            id: rect2
            x: 200
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "seagreen"

            onXChanged: console.log("rect2 x changed:", x)
        }
    }

    Keys.onSpacePressed: rect1.x = 0
}
```

Comment: Uhm, does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28415588/2538363) suit your needs?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo, I've tried using `mapToItem()` method, but limitation of such approach is that values involved in binding calculation do not change (these are relative `x` and `y` mentioned it the original question).

Comment: Ok, I've tested your code and now I get your point. Sorry for the wrong advice. :) Coordinates are relative to the parent hence you can only check that change in the parent. I guess the problem can get tricky (or expensive) if you have a hierarchy of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained on [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html), you can add signals among different elements. For your case, you can add the signal `xChanged` of `rect1` to that of `rect2`.

```
 Component.onCompleted: {

       rect1.xChanged.connect(rect2.xChanged);
 }
```

Also, note that it will print 200 still because its position hasn't changed relative to it's parent.

For that you could do something like :

```
onXChanged: console.log("rect2 x changed:", rect1.x + rect2.x)
```

Comment: You write: `note that it will print 200 still because its position hasn't changed relative to it's parent`. This is the reason why the signal won't be emitted.

Comment: @DmitryVolosnykh Signal of `rect1` will not be emitted but of `rect2` will. So I have connected the signal of `rect2` with that of `rect1` so that whenever parent's signal is emitted, child's get emitted as well. I tried and it worked, just give it a try.