# Get Item coordinates programmatically

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have QML `ApplicationWindow` named `ueWindowMain` and declared in `main.qml`. Inside it there is QML `StatusBar` named `ueStatusBar` with two icons, named `ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected` and `ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothPrinterConnected`, showing some state and one checkable QML `Button`, named `ueStaffSelector`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

import si.mikroelektronika 1.0

import "gui/items"

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueWindowMain

    title: qsTr("uBlagajna Mobile Client ver 0 revision 101")

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth

    visible: true

    opacity: 1.0

    contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation

    color: "black"

    statusBar: StatusBar
    {
        id: ueStatusBar

        height: 96

        clip: true

        antialiasing: true

        style: StatusBarStyle
        {
            background: Rectanglstrong texte
            {
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height

                color: "#303030"
            }   // background
        }   // style

        RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 8

            UeDatabaseStatusIndicator
            {
                id: ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected

                Layout.minimumWidth: 96
                Layout.preferredWidth: 96
                Layout.maximumWidth: 96
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                ueParamImageStatusOn: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueDbConnectionOk.png"
                ueParamImageStatusOff: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueDbConnectionError.png"
            }   // ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected

            UeBluetoothStatusIndicator
            {
                id: ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothPrinterConnected

                Layout.minimumWidth: 96
                Layout.preferredWidth: 96
                Layout.maximumWidth: 96
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                ueParamImageStatusOn: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueBtConnectionOk.png"
                ueParamImageStatusOff: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueBtConnectionError.png"
            }   // ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothPrinterConnected

            UeStaffSelector
            {
                id: ueStaffSelector

                Layout.minimumWidth: 96
                Layout.preferredWidth: 96
                Layout.maximumWidth: 96
                Layout.fillHeight: true
            }   // ueStaffSelector
        }   // RowLayout
    }   // ueStatusBar
}   // ueWindowMain
```

Now, those three items inside `StatusBar` are positioned using `RowLayout`. How can I calculate their coordinates inside QML code, i.e. programmatically?

Comment: Are you searching for the coordinates w.r.t. parent container/ main window? If that is the case that take a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28415588/2538363).

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo no, I am searching for coordinates of items inside `StatusBar`'s `RowLayout`.

Comment: You can still use the functions, take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve problem with following code chunk:

```
x: ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected.width+
   ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothPrinterConnected.width+2*ueStatusBarLayout.spacing
y: ueWindowMain.height-ueStatusBar.height-ueStaffView.height
```

and for now it seems it works fine.